# How to Display a Single Post Excerpt

Tags: php, loop, excerpt

Is it possible to show the excerpt for a known and single post (on the Home Page) while in `the loop`?

I tried each of these and none of them work:

```
<?php echo the_excerpt('10'); ?>
<?php echo the_excerpt(10); ?>
<?php $theExcerpt = get_the_excerpt('10'); echo $theExcerpt; ?>
<?php $theExcerpt = get_the_excerpt(10); echo $theExcerpt; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried get_post?  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Comment: No, I have not @shanebp. Per my OQ I only tried `the-excerpt` and `get_the_excerpt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_excerpt()` is one of a few template tags that do not accept a post ID as a parameter. Instead, you need to set up the global `$post`, run your tags, then restore it:

```
if ( $_post = get_post( 10 ) ) {
    setup_postdata( $post = $_post );
    the_excerpt();
    // Any other template tags for this post
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @TheDeadMedic...it worked exactly as I needed it to.